# Google Sign In integration in android with user input

Tags: java, android, gmail, gmail-api, android-signing

I want to integrate Google signIn in android application but don't want use Google Sign Button for authentication.

I want to authenticate user by his inputs like Email & Password. (User will enter email & password in editText) If it is possible, then how?

Please refer image

[image]

Comment: What kind of database are you using?

Comment: @AlexMamo I'm not using any kind of DB. I just want get input from user (Email & Password) authenticate to check valid Google Email ID & password. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

To authenticate with email and password i kindly recomand you using [Firebase authentication](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/password-auth). In my opinion is what you need. If you want to sign-in with Google, please take a look at this [Firebase authentication using Google](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/google-signin).

Hope it helps.